# Does 'Divide and conquer' yield O(log N) for unsorted array?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Following algorithm finds max QAZ. QAZ of an element is number of elements with higher value after that element's index. The popular answer is to use divide and solve using O(nLog(n))..

The array is not sorted. In worst case 'Divide&Conquer' will touch all n elements. Also 'for loop' will touch n/2 elements at worse.. How is it n*log(n).. Shouldn't it be O(n^2).. thanks

```
class QAZ:
    def __init__(self, min, qaz):
        self.min = min
        self.qaz = qaz


def max_qaz(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    def max_qaz_util(start, end):
        if end <= start:
            return QAZ(arr[end], 0)
        elif start == (end + 1):
            return QAZ(arr[start], 1) if arr[start] < arr[end] else QAZ(arr[end], 0)
        mid = int((start + end) / 2)
        left = max_qaz_util(start, mid)
        right = max_qaz_util(mid + 1, end)
        if left.min < right.min:
            left.qaz += end - mid
            return left
        else:
            for i in range(mid + 1, end + 1):
                if arr[i] > left.min:
                    left.qaz += 1
        return left if left.qaz > right.qaz else right

    result = max_qaz_util(0, n - 1)
    print("minval", result.min)
    print("qaz", result.qaz)

max_qaz([33, 25, 26, 58, 41, 59])
```

Reference - https://shirleyisnotageek.blogspot.com/2015/02/find-maximum-qaz.html?showComment=1481295499335#c2817927984213209920

Comment: Why negative vote without giving the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the for loop touches `n/2` elements in the worst case. The important fact here is that the division of the input is as even as possible. The amount of work done by the algorithm on `n` elements is `O(T(n))`, where the recurrence `T` is defined by

```
T(1) = O(1)
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n).
```

Case 2 of the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) applies, so `T(n) = O(n log n)`. This is very similar to merge sort.

Comment: I see.. Worst case 'for loop' is n/2 but that number is dropping by 2 every time... 1*n/2.. 2*n/4.. 4*n/8...  n*1...  thanks David